# Incorrect filr path in django clean() while validating file type

Tags: django

I have to validate file type in django forms. I am using python's `imghdr` to check file type (I have also used PIL, but error is same). This is my code

```
class GlobalImagesForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = GlobalImages
        exclude = ('id',)

    def clean_home_next_image(self):
        home_next_image = self.cleaned_data['home_next_image']
        file_type = imghdr.what(home_next_image)
        if file_type not in ['jpg', 'jpeg', 'png']:
            msg = gettext("Invalid file type. Accepted file type: %(types)s.") % {'days': "jpg, jpeg, png"}
            raise forms.ValidationError(msg)

        return home_next_image
```

But this giving error

```
The joined path (D:\admin\home\bg-cat.png) is located outside of the base path component (D:\Django\Vanloc\vanloc\media)
```

How can I get path of Image that user is trying to upload.

models.py

```
class GlobalImages(models.Model):
    home_next_image = models.ImageField(upload_to='admin/home/', default='/admin/home/bg-cat.png')
    testimonial_image = models.ImageField(upload_to='admin/home/', default='/admin/home/bg-testimonial.png')
    login_image = models.ImageField(upload_to='admin/home/', default='/admin/home/login-img.png')
    forget_pass_image = models.ImageField(upload_to='admin/home/', default='/admin/home/forgot-pass-img.png')
    registration_image = models.ImageField(upload_to='admin/home/', default='/admin/home/register-img.png')
    fidelity_top_image = models.ImageField(upload_to='admin/home/', default='/admin/home/fidelity-banner.png')
    fidelity_secondary_image = models.ImageField(upload_to='admin/home/', default='/admin/home/club-life-style.png')
    payment_thank_image = models.ImageField(upload_to='admin/home/', default='/admin/home/payment-thanku.png')
    rent_page_image = models.ImageField(upload_to='admin/home/', default='/admin/home/van-landing-1.png')
    home_top_image = models.ImageField(upload_to='admin/home/', default='/admin/home/119.png')
    home_notice_image = models.ImageField(upload_to='admin/home/', default='/admin/home/bg-covid.png')
```

Comment: Please add your `GlobalImages` model to the question, you may have set `upload_to` incorrectly on your `ImageField`

Comment: @IainShelvington, model added

Comment: The `default` for each `ImageField` should probably not start with a slash

Comment: I removed slashes from default. I don't know what will it change, but it not solve the problem. Thanks for suggestion